# infinite-scroll for 2 fixed height containers

Tags: ajax, plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

I have 2 fixed height columns for 2 different post-types. The goal is to get the infinite-scroll to work in both containers. I know that the **JetPack** infinite-scroll container parameter uses ID value in order for the module to function, but is it possible to use classes or two different ID's for this purpose? And if not, any other possible solutions?

[image]

My markup:

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="limit posts-a">
            <div class="content">
               <article>
               </article>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="limit posts-b">
            <div id="content" class="content">
               <article>
               </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

functions.php :

```
function mytheme_infinite_scroll_init() {
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
'type' => 'scroll',
'container' => 'content',
'footer' => 'limit',
'footer_widgets' => false,
) );
```